# Code to play audio client side (JSON.NET)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, audio

I have installed the JSON.NET framework in visual studios for my C# emulator which runs a game accessible via a browser

Users from around the world can play the game so I want them to hear audio upon executing a command.

I don't know Javascript therefore i'm hoping someone can comment the code which can play audio via a .mp3 / wav file (client side).

For example a game like club penguin is accessible via a browser and they have audio which is client side so other penguins can hear it.

If the audio was server side the user would have to download the emulator in order to hear it. But in this case users are not downloading anything they are simply playing the game.

Comment: Is it a flash game then? If so you would need to modify the flash file, flash has quite extensive audio capabilities. Your question seems a bit vague, I can't see how Json.net and emulators factor into this.

Comment: It's not a flash game , a example of this game would be https://peace.wtf/

Comment: That doesn't necessarily help me understand what technologies are used (I won't create an account to answer a question on SO), but if it's an HTML game then I don't see how you can get around this by using anything other than javascript, especially if you need it to be dynamic based on user activity (so something like a simple <audio> tag wouldn't necessarily be of much help).

Comment: The website is in HTML although the client itself relies on the emulator to run which is written in C#. In conclusion i'm just seeking the code which can play audio for JSON.NET which will work in visual studios (C#) sorry if i'm not being exactly clear. Then from having this code I can just implement it in to a command within the emulator

Comment: So if the emulator outputs HTML and presumably javascript, which is the rendered by the browser, then you need to tell the emulator to output audio, and we couldn't possibly help without knowing what emulator it is.

Comment: It doesn't output javascript , there is a client.php file which has the swfs linked and such although the game cannot run without the emulator. You can take a look here https://pastebin.com/BrBC6bZu. I know you can't do much without the emu so i'm just asking for the code then I can work with what I've got. Yes the emulator does follow a certain protocol although i'm pretty sure if I just know the code to output audio for JSON.NET which can be implemented in to visual studios it will work

Comment: Json.Net has nothing to do with audio. And I don't think anyone can give you code without knowing the language, the framework or any bit of additional detail...

Comment: Of course not , hence why this question was aimed at people who have had experience with this framework. Why anyone who hasn't had experience with this framework would try to answer is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: But which framework is that then? It can't be Json.Net because Json.Net has nothing to do with audio. It's also not really a framework, it's a library that deals only with serializing and deserializing data in JSON format.

Comment: Obviously JSON.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json please read title of threads before commenting? As mentioned before I don't know JS so perhaps users can recommend a different framework which deals with audio

Comment: I have extensive experience with Json.Net and it has nothing to do with audio, so your question is flawed. I suggest you take some time to understand the technologies you use a bit more in depth.

Comment: Disregarding that someone who does know a framework which deals with audio could link me and then tell me the code? I'm not asking anyone to learn the protcol of my emulator and adding it for me that would be spoon feeding . I don't know JS nor plan or learning to just need this

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists: a framework that magically integrates with some unknown thing you already have, and sends audio to a browser to be played when something happens inside a swf file inside that browser (if I understood the infrastructure correctly).

Comment: I've seen people in the past utilize websockets or something to achieve this. I know javascript can communicate with the client and output audio if using a certain framework i'm just asking for a framework and the code not anyones opinion on if they believe or such.